# Word that expresses agreement of unspoken conditions

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or concept that means - "We have explicitly agreed to these terms but by making this deal, you're are also bound by implicit, unspoken ethical constraints that between us is assumed to be understood."

A word that refers to just the unspoken agreement in such a context would also help.

Comment: That’s called a ***loophole***.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun, an adjective, a verbal noun, or something else? How would you use this word in a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

> ***[tacit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tacit)*** - implied or indicated (as by an act or by silence) but not actually expressed

I'd say, though, it's harder to argue that the ethical considerations are understood by both parties.   *Tacit* is more along the lines of, "I said, 'Any objections?' and you stood silently by" or "you stood there and watched me do it!"

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.